# Sendgrid receive email locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, griddler

I am trying to implement sendgrid parse API using the 'griddler' gem in my rails application. The problem is how can I test it locally? And how to receive email in my local machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are a couple ways to test SendGrid's Parse Webhook locally.

The easiest is to just simulate the Webhook by POSTing data to your endpoint yourself (via cURL or some other mechanism, like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) [[example](http://d.pr/i/bY8a)]). The [SendGrid Parse Webhook Docs](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) has an example of the payload that will be posted to your server, so you may mimic that.

The second option, which allows for end-to-end testing rather than just simulation is by creating a tunnel your local machine and provide SendGrid with the URL of the tunnel. There are a number of free services that allow you to do just that very easily:

- https://ngrok.com/
- http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Answer (score 1):

If I may self-promote, I created a Ruby gem that does this:

https://github.com/ccallebs/pokey-sendgrid

It runs alongside your server and generates SendGrid webhook requests at regular intervals.